# Update multiple rows in MySql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, sql-update

I have this script that read parsed xml (external):

```
<?php
//mysql connection
$con2 = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con2)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$selectdb = mysql_select_db("test_db", $con2);
if (!$selectdb)
  {
 die('Database not used: ; ' . mysql_error());
  }

//simplexml load xml file
   $jackpots =  simplexml_load_file('https://www.123.com/xmldata.xml');

//loop through parsed xmlfeed and print output
      foreach ($jackpots->jackpot as $jackpot) {

                     foreach ($jackpots->jackpot as $jackpot) {
                     printf("gameId: %s\n", $jackpot->gameId);
                     printf("gameName: %s\n", $jackpot->gameName);
                     printf("amount: %s\n", $jackpot->amount);
                     printf("currency: %s\n", $jackpot->currency);
//insert into databse
foreach ($jackpots->gameId as $jackpot) {
                               mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET amount=$jackpot->amount")
                               or die(mysql_error());}
//show updated records
            printf ("Records inserted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
            }
        }
//close connection
 mysql_close($con2);

?>
```

Obviously, I have a table (my_table) in database that contains all colums (gameId, gameName, amount and currency).

I need to update the "amount" column for every "gameId" column.
When I run the script below, I got an update but all the "amounts" are the same.
Can I have some support, please?
Where is my error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot the `WHERE` clause. Be careful, you really can f..k things up badly with this.

Comment: nice sql injection hole... hopefully 123.com would never register little [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com) at your school

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include the gameId in your query!

Like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET amount=$jackpot->amount WHERE gameId = '".$jackpot->gameId."'")
```

Be careful, though, when you insert variables hard-coded into the query like this.
You should escape the variables before to avoid SQL injection vulnerability.
It would probably be good to look into PHP frameworks like Code Igniter, Zend or Laravel to get you some basic functionality setup in these tasks.

Comment: Yes... I'm a complete i*iot... :D

Answer (score 3):

You need a `where` statement to target a specific row, your statement updates the entire table each time in the loop, that's why you get the same amounts, the last amount in the loop

> mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET amount=$jackpot->amount WHERE gameId=$jackpot->gameId);